# Segments duplicated during fork()?

Tags: c, unix, memory, stack, fork

I have studied that during a fork, the data and code segment of the parent process gets duplicated into the child process.

Kindly see the program below.

```
int main()
{
   int a = 5;
   pid_t pid;

   pid = fork();

   if(pid == 0)
   {
      printf("In child a = %d",a);
   }

   else
   {
     printf("In parent a = %d",a);
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Here a is in the stack segment of parent process as it is declared inside the function, `main()`. The child process should only get copy of the code and data segment of the parent process and not the stack during `fork()`. But when I run the program, I can see that the child process is able to access the variable 'a' also. Thats means somehow the stack of parent process is also copied into the child process.

Kindly tell me the reason for this and correct me if my understanding is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check the [docs](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fork.html) again.  `fork` creates an "exact copy of the calling process".  Admittedly, there are a lot of exceptions, but the stack is not one of them.

Also, if the stack wasn't duplicated, the very common idiom (also used in your code) of checking the return value (almost always a stack variable) from `fork` would fail.  There wouldn't *be* a stack position for `pid` unless the stack (including stack pointer) was duplicated.

Comment: So what i should understand is that all the data segments: stack,heap,code and data segments are duplicated into the child from the parent during fork()?

Comment: Yes.  Everything is duplicated, unless it's called out as an exception.

Answer (score 2):

That isn't a good test - as Matthew has pointed out, fork() gives you an exact copy of the parent process, including the stack (else the child would be unable to return from this function).

A better test is to modify 'a' in the parent and observe it in the child, like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main()
{
    int a = 5;
    pid_t pid;

    pid = fork();

    if (pid == 0)
    {
        sleep(5);
        printf("In child a = %d\n",a);
    }
    else
    {
        a++;
        printf("In parent a = %d\n",a);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

and the result is correct:

```
pandora:~/tmp$ cc -o x x.c
pandora:~/tmp$ ./x
In parent a = 6
pandora:~/tmp$ In child a = 5
```

Comment: Yeah, i know the concept you are talking about. Although the segments of parent are duplicated into the child, their segments are independent because 2 processes have their own address space. So i understand what you are trying to say using the example given.Thanks.